# Add Mime Type to a virtual directory

Tags: c#, iis, mime-types, virtual-directory

I want to add a MIME type to the newly created virtual directory, which is under 'Default Web Site'.

```
using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
{
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
var vdir = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["VDir"];
}
```

I haven't been able to find appropriate examples/documentation where I can do it for a virtual directory (and not for a website), without using `DirectoryServices`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it like this (slight modification of [the example on IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap)):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample
{
   private static void Main()
   {
      using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
      {
         Configuration vDirConfig = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site", "/VDir");
         ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = vDirConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
         ConfigurationElementCollection staticContentCollection = staticContentSection.GetCollection();

         ConfigurationElement mimeMapElement = staticContentCollection.CreateElement("mimeMap");
         mimeMapElement["fileExtension"] = @"bla";
         mimeMapElement["mimeType"] = @"application/blabla";
         staticContentCollection.Add(mimeMapElement);

         ConfigurationElement mimeMapElement1 = staticContentCollection.CreateElement("mimeMap");
         mimeMapElement1["fileExtension"] = @"tab";
         mimeMapElement1["mimeType"] = @"text/plain";
         staticContentCollection.Add(mimeMapElement1);

         serverManager.CommitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```